# Using a webcam and OpenCV-Python 3.4.0, how do I keep a drawing function in one window from appearing on to another window?

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, opencv

[Two Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7F38Z.png)

Hello everyone,

On the right of the picture link named "Two Windows", I have a window named 'frame' which shows a green square and a cyan circle. On the left, there is a window named 'binary' which shows the square and circle in white.

The binary window shows in white objects that are moving.

What can I do so that the drawing functions do not show in the 'binary' window and only stay in the 'frame' window?

I'd greatly appreciate any help I can receive.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

ret, last_frame = cap.read()

if last_frame is None:
    exit()

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    if frame is None:
        exit()

    binary = cv2.absdiff(last_frame, frame)
    binary = cv2.cvtColor(binary, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) 
    ret, binary = cv2.threshold(binary,50,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY) 

    last_frame = frame.copy()

    #Rectangle
    frame = cv2.rectangle(frame,(0,0),(320,240),(0,255,0),3)

    #Circle
    vRow, vCol, vCH = frame.shape
    cirR = 30
    cirRowPos = int(vRow/2)
    cirColPos = int(vCol-cirR) - int(vCol*0.05)
    frame = cv2.circle(frame,(cirColPos, cirRowPos), cirR, (255,255,0), 3)

    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    cv2.imshow('binary', binary)

    if cv2.waitKey(33) >= 0:
        break

    last_frame = frame

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the line 'last_frame = frame" and I added "last_frame = frame.copy()" before my drawing functions.